# Save JPG image on matlab without changing the quantization table

Tags: matlab, save, jpeg

I'm working on a steganography method, and I'm trying to test it against noise and Gaussian low pass filter.
I edited the image, and I want to save the changes, I'm using imsave, and imwrite, but both methods change the quantization table of the my image and the huffman tables, I'm looking for a way to save the image without altered the quantization tables and the huffman tables.

Comment: How do you edit the image and why is it important if the tables are changed? If I recall correctly, the quantization tables depend on the compression (or quality) factor, which you can adjust manually, even though there is a default value.

Comment: As I said I'm developing a steganographic method, and I used a modified quantization table, so i don't want matlab to change it. I edited the image using 2 different function:
1_imnoise(image,'gaussian',m,v);
2_GFilter = fspecial('gaussian',[size size],variance);
LPF_image = imfilter(image,GFilter,'same');

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to save a jpeg image with a specific quantization table? You'll want to write your own jpeg encoder based on your needs. `imsave` and `imwrite` take an array of pixels and save it in the requested format based on some internal encoders. You can't change those.

Comment: It is not possible to control the quantization tables in MATLAB.  You can only change certain parameters, such as the quantization quality, bit depth and so on: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?refresh=true#btx0ykd .  If you want to control the quantization table, you should use an actual JPEG codec library so you have full control in doing that.  The canonical implementation of the JPEG codec can be found on the Independent JPEG Group's website: http://www.ijg.org/

Comment: I developed a JPEG encoder with a specific quantization tables, and huffman tables, and i saved the image as jpeg. but when I read the image using imread and add some noise using imnoise, i want to save the modified image over the old one without modifying quantization and huffman tables